# Oracle REGEXP_LIKE syntax or trigger for key value pair string validation

Tags: regex, oracle

I need to validate a string (in oracle) which contains key-value pairs in the below formats:

```
ABC=DEF
ABC=DEF|GHI=JKL
```

I've tried quite a few regexp expressions but I can't seem to get it to work correctly. I've hunted around and found a few people trying to do the same thing but couldn't find any solution that works.

I need to ensure values going into a DB table column are in the above format.

Is anyone able to help me out?

Thanks,
-Steve

Answer (score 0):

You could try the below regex.

```
^([[:alpha:]]+=[[:alpha:]]+|[[:alpha:]]+=[[:alpha:]]+\|[[:alpha:]]+=[[:alpha:]]+)$
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/gC1iN7/1)

Answer (score 0):

You can use regexp_like for get your expected results. i.e:

```
select cad from   
(select 'ABC=DEF|GHI=JKL' cad from dual union all
select 'ABC=DEF|GHI=JKL|' cad from dual union all
select 'ABC=DEF|ABC=' cad from dual)
where regexp_like(cad,'^(((\w+=\w+\|)+(\w+=\w+))|(\w+=\w+))$')
```

Output:

```
CAD             
----------------
ABC=DEF|GHI=JKL
```